# Maven dependency resolution

Tags: maven-2, grails, groovy, dependency-management

I would like to use Maven for dependency resolution only in my Grails application, i.e. I will continue to use Grails commands such as `grails war` and `grails test-app` to build and test my app. According to the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7.8%20Maven%20Integration) this is possible.

Apparently I need to specify the following in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    pom true
}
```

And I then specify my dependencies in my pom.xml using the usual Maven XML syntax. What should the rest of this pom.xml contain, e.g. what should I specify for the `<packaging>`? I think I might need to create this pom.xml using the [maven-publisher](http://grails.org/plugin/maven-publisher) Grails plugin, but the documentation doesn't say that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use maven to build grails application, the suggested approach is documented [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.5%20Ant%20and%20Maven)

To convert an existing grails project to maven, run

```
mvn org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:1.3.2:create-pom -DgroupId=com.mycompany
```

Comment: I only want to use Maven for dependency resolution. I want to use the standard grails commands for everything else

Comment: @Don. Sure. Your problem was what to put in pom.xml.  This command should create the necessary entries.  I guess you are free to continue to use grails commands.